# .htaccess problem virtual subpath

Tags: .htaccess

i spent tons of hours to solve a problem without success, so i'm here now.

If you visit my website example.com everything looks nice (y)

But when you click on a navigation point the url will change to http://example.com/subpath/nodetitle

How i'm able to get a url like this:
http://example.com/noteditle

I tried with RewriteBase / and uncomment the $base_url without any success.

Please help me, thanks!